# Подсказки при вводе в Telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Можно ли сделать, так чтобы при вводе сообщения боту всплывали подсказки вероятного набора, хранящиеся допустим в контейнере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, в текущей реализации (как api так и протокола клиентского приложения) никак нельзя: бот получает сообщение только когда пользователь завершит ввод сообщения и нажмёт кнопку "отправить".

Максимум вы сможете подсказки на каждую букву сделать в виде `InlineKeyboardMarkup` и жать по одной, но это будет настолько странный вид, что вряд ли кто-то посчитает это удобным. Это же не набор текста, это именно кнопки, тем более их располагать будет неудобно при таком количестве - по одной кнопке на каждую букву.

Как альтернативу просто по `/start` (или `/help`) выводите список возможных команд.